# Is .@ a Javascript symbol?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, e4x

I find the following code in some file:

```
var node = <title />;
node.@name = "titleName";
```

The node is

```
<title>
 <name>titleName<name/>
</title>
```

So What's the `.@` operator meaning?

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript.

Comment: While are we at it @meagar, do we know which language would such symbol belong to?

Comment: @CppLearner My best guess would be, a template file.

Comment: And then, there's all of those languages that compile to JavaScript.  My guess was going to be TypeScript or something, but then I saw `var node = <title />;`, and I can't imagine that would be valid in anything.

Comment: I think we should upvote. This is a valid question. But kudos to pswg helping figuring out. We shouldn't be harsh on "strange" question like this.

Comment: @CppLearner But then how can pswg earn the reversal badge?

Comment: Maybe he has it already, considering the amount of gold badges he has.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks like [ECMAScript for XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_for_XML) (E4X), an extension for ECMAScript (on which JavaScript is based). It was standardized in [ECMA-357](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-357.pdf), but it was not widely adopted by the major browser vendors, and was dropped from later ECMAScript standards. However, it is still supported by some engines, including [ActionScript 3.0](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e72.html).

It's used for working with XML more gracefully. The `.@` syntax references an XML attribute within an `XmlNode`, and in this case, `node.@name = "titleName"` sets the attribute `name` on `node` to the value `"titleName"`.

Comment: I'm using AS3.0 actually :-)